# Json writes doesn't seem to be working when extending an abstract class

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-json

I have a base class that I inherit from for my case class, and when I use the regular Json.writes it doesn't seem to include the inherited fields.

```
implicit val userResponseWrites = Json.writes[UserRespopnse]

case class UserResponse(var userId: Int, var name: String) extends BaseResponse

abstract class BaseResponse(var success: Boolean = false, var message: String = "")
```

Then json response doesn't include the success and message fields from the BaseResponse class.

Is it possible for this to work or do I have to manually write out my writes formatter?

Comment: This doesn't compile. What are you trying to achieve with `BaseResponse`, and how are those values to be filled? `UserResponse` isn't supplying `success` and `message` to the `BaseResponse` constructor on extension.

Comment: For a start, if you are going to extend BaseResponse like that you need to have values for the default constructor. e.g. case class UserResponse(var userId: Int, var name: String) extends BaseResponse(true, "message")

Comment: It would also be good to rethink fields need to be vars. By having them as vals its safer to pass the object around without worry about it being modified but another function.

Comment: @LionelPort True but they are simple objects that I use to return to my view pages, I like having them as vars so I can change the values in my controller action methods.

Comment: @m-z I added default values.  BaseResponse is a blueprint on what I will build all my response objects from.  So how do I fix the problem of the extended baseresponse values not being written to my json response.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON `reads` and `writes` macros use the `apply` and `unapply` methods of a case class respectively. They don't simply just read and write all of the members of the class. Through inheritance, your class essentially looks like this:

```
case class UserResponse(var userId: Int, var name: String) {
   var success: Boolean = false
   var message: String = ""
}
```

Only the `userId` and `name` members will be picked up by the macro. One (kind of ugly) way to work around this and still use the macro is to drop the getters/setters from the abstract class, and let the case class define them:

```
abstract class BaseResponse(success: Boolean, message: String)
case class UserResponse(var userId: Int, var name: String, var success: Boolean = false, var message: String = "") 
    extends BaseResponse(success, message)
```

The only other alternative I see is manually defining the `Writes` for each class.

That said, there is probably a better way to accomplish all of this than using vars, though it's hard to tell what without more context.